# Urllib and concurrency - Python

Tags: python, http, concurrency, wsgi, urllib

I'm serving a python script through **WSGI**. The script accesses a web resource through **urllib**, computes the resource and then returns a value.

Problem is that **urllib doesn't seem to handle many concurrent requests to a precise URL**.

As soon as the requests go up to 30 concurrent request, the requests slow to a crawl! :(

---

Help would be  much appreciated! :D

Comment: Are you sure that urllib is the bottleneck and not some environment constraints such as sending your requests via a proxy?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, `urllib` doesn't do much concurrency. Every time you `urlopen`, it has to set up the connection, send the HTTP request, and get the status code and headers from the response (and possibly handle a redirect from there). So although you get to read the body of the response at your own pace, the majority of the waiting time for the request will have already happened.

If you need more concurrency, you'll probably have to pick up some kind of asynchronous network IO tool (eg. [Eventlet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/eventlet/) seems to have a suitable example on its front page), or just launch each `urlopen` in its own thread.

Comment: The GIL prevents true concurrency even when using separate threads (although it will look like concurrency). Separate process are required in order for true concurrency (which is what eventlet does).